# Use a void* argument to pass integer OR a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, variant

I want to detect if a value of a void* type input function argument is an integer or a pointer. Currently, I'm passing the integer only (this is Midnight Commander source):

```
mc_event_raise (MCEVENT_GROUP_CORE, 
    "clipboard_file_from_ext_clip",
        (void*)(intptr_t)clip_id);
```

However I would also like to sometimes pass a string (char *) in the same parameter, as extending the API would be difficult. I know that this is wrong, however, maybe there is a fully legal way to obtain such effect ? My ideas:
– the addresses are in general aligned to 4 or 8 bytes,   so I've could skip such values from the clip_id (jump over them) and then decode the value? `if (data % 8) then clip_id = decode_clip_id(data);` ?
– maybe pointers cannot be as small as 10…20 and a simple check would be sufficient?
– other ideas…?

Comment: Next question: *I have a parameter that's sometimes an int and sometimes a pointer: how can I tell the difference?*

Comment: All of your ideas have been used in real software before, reliably. Windows uses them all the time. But how much do you care whether your program won't work on more exotic computers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A problem like this can be solved with a structure containing a union and a tag.

```
struct EventData {
    enum { EV_IS_INT, EV_IS_PTR } type;
    union {
        intptr_t v_int;
        void * v_ptr;
    };
};
```

So, you can then pass a pointer to this `EventData`, and the callback can decode whether to access `v_int` or `v_ptr`, based on the value of `type`.

```
    struct EventData *ed = makeEventData (EV_IS_INT, clip_id);
    mc_event_raise (MCEVENT_GROUP_CORE, 
                    "clipboard_file_from_ext_clip",
                    ed);
```

If the event is completed asynchronously, you may need to create the event dynamically, and then the callback function would have to release the memory when the callback is done with the argument.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good solution (unless there's some flaw in it, which I currently don't see). I will migrate to this method at some point, however I've solved it differently: I know that void* will be char* and the integer that I want to pass will be small, max 30. So I'm passing two the same pointers – to a char. I then peek only the first byte and check, if it's lower than 30 and if it is – this means that it's the integer. More, the char* string must start with / (it's an absolute path), code 47. So the solution is fully reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Windows does a lot of this hackery with their HANDLEs and resource IDs.

Your integer needs to have a defined valid range. Anything outside of that range is probably a pointer.

Almost all operating systems reserve low memory areas. You can probably assume that the 16-bit range 0 to 65535 is not a pointer. Beyond that gets iffy.

If your code needs to be portable to things like embedded RTOS or freestanding environments then you cannot assume anything about pointers.

In any case you will probably want some sort of function to create values to pass into your void* which will have an `assert` or `abort` to avoid accidentally creating invalid values.

Comment: Upvoted, but 0 is a valid integer value and pointer value.

Comment: @jxh Yeah, and the hypothetical `clip_id_from_string` should call `abort` if it is passed a NULL pointer value.